# Restart docker container with a new image when it dies

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running an image that has a bug which occasionally causes the container to crash. I have a new image that fixes that bug. I'd like to keep the old image running for as long as possible since as long as it's running, it's in a good state. The container is currently running with `restart=always`.

Is there a way to have the container start with the new, bugfixed image only after it dies?

Comment: How have you started the container in the first place? Using plain docker or some orchestration software? Because using Kubernetes to orchestrate your containers should allow you doing exactly those things. Like rolling out new images progressively, while being able to fall back to older images in case a new one causes unexpected problems. If you are interested, check out their [website](https://kubernetes.io/).

Comment: I started the container just with `docker run ...`

Comment: There is command like [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) to update, among others, the restart policy of your running container. So, maybe you could disable `restart=always` and figure out a way to start a new image as soon as the termination of the former container is detected? Other that, I also don't really have a concrete idea unfortunately. But maybe there are other helpful docker commands besides `docker update`.